# Is there an R function to animate a number counter?

Tags: r, numbers, jquery-animate, counter

I was wondering if anyone knows how to animate a number counter in R. Or somewhere else if that is possible? I want a number to go from one number to the next whilst increasing in size.

For example, to go from 1 to 456 whilst counting but also increasing in size whilst doing this.

Thanks a lot for your help,
Best wishes.

Comment: Would you add an example to what you wish ?

Comment: Of course: For example, in Arial font on a white background. I want the number 1 to count upwards to 456 in the time of 3 seconds. And additionally (if possible): whilst the number is counting upwards to 456 to be slowly increasing in physical size too (for the size to also show the magnitude of the increase).

Comment: Do you want this to happen in Shiny, markdown, the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure on how you plan on using the number counter. If this just about creating an animation of a number counter, you could use `gganimate`.

Here is an example of a counter increasing up to 20.

```r
library(ggplot)
library(gganimate)

n_max <- 20L
p <- ggplot(data.frame(n = 1L:n_max)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = as.integer(n), size = n)) +
    theme_void() +
    guides(size = "none") +
    scale_size_area(max_size = 50) +
    transition_time(as.integer(n))

an <- animate(p, nframes = n_max, duration = 3)
anim_save("animation.gif", an)
```

[image]

If you increase `n_max` you'll need to adjust the number of frames (and probably the FPS) to meet your needs regarding smoothness of the animation.